# ¿Qué función realiza esta linea?

Tags: c

Disculpen estuve investigando sobre esta función `system("ps -ax")` pero no encontré nada, quisiera saber que función realiza en **C**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`system`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) es una función estándar de **C**, se declara como `int system(const char *command)` y lo que hace es ejecutar el comando especificado en `command` por medio del interprete de comandos del sistema. En el ejemplo que mostras lo que se está haciendo es invocar a una herramienta estándar de Unix/Linux [`ps`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) que muestra los procesos activos, el parámetro `-ax` muestra todos los procesos al estilo BSD.

Comment: Gracias Patricio, ya me quedo mas claro

Answer (score 2):

Como puedes ver en la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/), la función `system()` (declarada en  `stdlib.h`) ejecuta un comando externo. Hay varios detalles que dependen del sistema operativo.

En tu caso, estás corriendo (imagino que en Linux) el programa [ps](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps), que lista procesos activos. Por supuesto, `ps` no tiene nada que ver con `C`.

Comment: Gracias leonbloy, me quedo mas claro